# How to select each row in the result to a different text file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using sql server and I ran a query that resulted in 5000 rows. I want each row to be saved as a separate text file. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There is always a way. But the question here is why? That is a lot of files.

Comment: I have a column that has a full xml as a data in it and had a business requirement to have each row as a text file

Answer (score 3):

If you rather do it in TSQL.  Now, I can't take credit for stored procedure, it was lifted from SO some time ago.

You would have to modify the initial query and DESTINATION in Step 3.

> 1) Required provided you have the appropriate rights

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

> 2) Create the Stored Procedure -- MUST Supply YourDatabaseName

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[prc-Write-To-File] (@text as Varchar(Max), @Filename Varchar(200)) AS
Begin
    Declare @Object int,@rc int,@FileID Int

    EXEC @rc = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @Object OUT
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @Object , 'OpenTextFile' , @FileID OUT , @Filename , 2 , 1
    Set @text = Replace(Replace(Replace(@text,'&','&'),'<' ,'<'),'>','>')
    EXEC @rc = sp_OAMethod @FileID , 'WriteLine' , Null , @text
    Exec @rc = [YourDatabaseName].dbo.sp_OADestroy @FileID
    Declare @Append bit
    Select @Append = 0
    If @rc <> 0
    Begin
        Exec @rc = [YourDatabaseName].dbo.sp_OAMethod @Object, 'SaveFile',null,@text ,@Filename,@Append
    End
    Exec @rc = [YourDatabaseName].dbo.sp_OADestroy @Object
End
```

> 3) Then Execute from within a CURSOR

```
Declare @ID int,@String varchar(max)
Declare @Cursor as Cursor;

Set @Cursor = Cursor For
Select top 5 OD_Nr,OD_Title from OD  --<< Your QUERY goes here  

Open @Cursor;
Fetch Next From @Cursor into @ID, @String;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
 Print cast(@ID as VARCHAR (50)) + ' ' + @String;
 Declare @Destination varchar(150) 
 Set @Destination = 'c:\working\test_' +cast(@ID as varchar(25))+'.txt'
 Exec [dbo].[prc-Write-To-File] @String,@Destination 
 Fetch Next From @Cursor Into @ID, @String;
End

Close @Cursor;
Deallocate @Cursor;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SSIS, I was going to type it all out, but here is a site where he has it detailed with screenshots.
https://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/